# JS function output to HTML input element

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

How do I return the output of JS function to my HTML input element.

Form like this .

[image]

Now on my click Run - Script i execute simple script

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control" onclick="$('#output').toggle();"  onclick="Task_1(document.getElementById('word').value,document.getElementById('repeat').value)">Run script</button>

function Task_1(word, repeat_number) {
  console.log("------------------------------------");
  var Output = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < repeat_number; i++) {
     Output = Output + word;
  }
 console.log(Output);
 return Output;
}
```

An the output of that script should be show on additional input box

[image]

I tried with

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = Output.toString();
```

Complete : [JS FIDDLE - Task#1](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/231697/)

Also: If i rotate two commented lines

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ...
<script src="h ...
```

it gives me the great output as i wanted but then the modal window doesn't work. The only difference is in version 4.1.2 and 3.3.7 how to bypass it.

> Note: Learner who is going through tutorials. Point me at start so i
>   wont go in wrong direction.

Comment: If you want to cheat a bit: `var result = word.repeat(repeat_number)` :)

Comment: @JonasWilms hahah let me first get the syntax here. Its just an example tomorrow ill need to use the for loops to access the world banks transactions and i wont be able to use libraries :P :P

Comment: Could you show us the version with the *i tried with* part? that should actually work.

Comment: @JonasWilms its in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/231697/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your submit button.

You have:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control" onclick="$('#output').toggle();"  onclick="Task_1(document.getElementById('word').value,document.getElementById('repeat').value)">Run script</button>
```

Notice that you have two `onclick` attributes within the button. Only the first one is executed. To execute multiple JavaScript statements on each click you need a single `onclick` attribute with the statements separated by a semi colon.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control" onclick="$('#output').toggle(); Task_1(document.getElementById('word').value,document.getElementById('repeat').value)">Run script</button>
```

You might like to consider attaching the event handler in your JavaScript code rather than in your HTML. This is usually considered best practice.